# Cassandra process killed on exit

Tags: cassandra, datastax, coreos

When I run dsc cassandra on CoreOS(tarball) using telnet everything comes up fine. But when i close the telnet session, it kills the process. How do i keep the cassandra server running?

I tried sudo bin/cassandra and sudo bin/cassandra -f 
both didnt help.

I have no issues in other OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option  Description
-f  Start the cassandra process in foreground. The default is to start as background process.
-h  Help.
-p filename     Log the process ID in the named file. Useful for stopping Cassandra by killing its PID.
-v  Print the version and exit.
```

When you are starting cassandra using -f it runs in foreground, hence it will stop as soon as terminal is closed. Same is true for background process.
This will happen with any application you run in telnet session.
You can try
`sudo service cassandra start` OR `nohup bin/cassandra` this will keep your application running even when terminal is closed

Comment: tried with nohup, but still process is killed on exit from session. Checking on how to run it as a service in coreos

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Cassandra as a systemd service, as described here: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/getting-started-with-systemd.html

Running in the foreground with `cassandra -f` as your `ExecStart=` command will allow systemd to manage the state of the process (ideally inside a container).

While this is a bit different than what you're used to, it will lead to an overall more stable mechanism since you'll be using an init system that understands dependency chains, restart and reboot behavior, logging, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Run the process in a screen or tmux session. Detaching from the screen session should allow the process to keep running.